# no sound playing quicktime on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, quicktime

I just bought and downloaded a bunch of video tutorials in quicktime (.mov), but to my distress they play without sound.
Other videos on my computer play sound, even quicktime files I  made myself got sound.

Just these downloaded files. I probably miss a codec, but how do I know which one?

My system is windows 7 final x64 and I use the standard on board sound card of my shuttle SP35P2 Pro Barebone.

[The preview video of the tutorial](http://luminous-landscape.com/video_journal/c2p-preview.shtml) I bought neither does play sound, probably for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [QuickTime DirectShow Source Filter](http://www.medialooks.com/products/directshow_filters/quicktime_filter.html):

> MediaLooks QuickTime Source is a
>   DirectShow source filter that allows
>   developers to playback Apple QuickTime
>   media (.MOV, .AMR, .MP4, etc.) via the
>   native QuickTime runtime. The filter
>   requires QuickTime Player (7.0 or
>   higher) to be available on the
>   computer.
>
> Since the native QuickTime runtime
>   code is used for playback, there is no
>   degradation of quality compared to the
>   original QuickTime player.
>
> This product is free for end users if
>   used for personal non-commercial
>   goals.

Comment: Sooo, what would I have to do to hear sound? I can see the video very well, just the sound is missing.

Comment: Did you install QuickTime? Some of Apple's codecs are proprietary, so you absolutely need the original codecs, not open source re-engineered ones. QuickTime itself is best for seeing .mov videos. The purpose of the DirectShow Source Filter is to allow these codecs to be used by Windows programs that use DirectX, such as Windows Media Player.

Comment: If you're already using QuickTime for these videos and they don't work, then they are simply corrupted.

Comment: Duh, I had not installed QuickTime - Win 7 did play most of the .mov files, and it did show the video content, but as you wrote, the sound codec seemed to be proprietary to QuickTime itself.
And since Windows did play the files I did not even notice I had not installed it.

Answer (score 0):

This [pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_lite_codec_pack.htm) include all the codecs I know and some utilities and players that can give more details about the encoder used.

Comment: Installed the standard version (since I do not intend to encode), even rebootet, but alas, still no sound :(
And the pack is broken: the mediainfo.exe is missing, even though the menu item was installed.

Comment: try the pro one and why not different players ?

Comment: If K-Lite Codec Pack does not work, something really is wrong. I've never had any problems with it, no matter what version of Windows I've used.

Comment: @Revolter. I tried the player in the K-Lite pack.

@Alex, @Revolter: can you play the video I added a link to in my question with sound? Maybe you can tell me which audio codec it uses?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 (and maybe Vista?) supports a different volume per application.

[image]

Open the Volume Mixer while you play a movie in QuickTime. QuickTime should have its own volume slider. See if it's muted or set to a very low level.

Comment: Yep, the mixer is on, sound is on max - As I wrote in my question **other quicktime files play sound**. Just these don't.  Does the linked video play sound for you?

Comment: Can't check now, the videos are blocked by my corporate proxy.